# Sample Size Determination for Inter- and Intra-rater Reliability

Tags: estimation, sample-size, reliability, agreement-statistics

I am going to conduct a study on the intra- and inter- rater reliability of chemical assessment. I am having some problem to calculate the optimal sample size calculation for both raters and chemicals. since my population for raters are 163 and chemicals are 60. How do I have to calculate the optimal sample size?

Comment: How do you define (inter and intra) reliability? What precision of measurement do you want to achieve? What are you going to test: mean values of reliability for chemicals, difference between different raters, or something else? Have you decided which statistical test you will use? Adding those details to the question will help us give you the correct answer. :)

Comment: I define the inter-rater reliability as the reliability of the assessment between chemical assessors (rater) while intra-rater reliability as the reliability of the assessment within the chemical assessors in second trial. I am going to test the different of scores between assessors. my question in my study is what if the assessors have different scores for each chemical?. I am planning to use statisitcal test of Intraclass Correlation under Random Factorial Design. Thank you for your concern :)

Comment: the scores defined as score of chemical exposure

Comment: Consider editing the question to include those information from the responses in the comments. :) I'm not familiar with Intraclass Correlation, but, hopefully, other users are and will give you the answers you need. Checking if chemicals got different scores from different assessors seems like a use case for ANOVA to me, if that is of any help.

Comment: If you are ok with a little programming, you can determine sample sizes with simulations.